# Azure Performance counter - Http Service Url Groups

Tags: azure

I want to monitor the number of HTTP requests handled by my web role instance.

In order to do so I used the Http Service Url Groups category and chose the AllRequests counter.

I then started a load test against my role and noticed that the HTTP counter did not increase.

Could someone please explain why the HTTP counters failed to increase and what are the best counters to use to monitor network use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, I use the W3SVC_W3WP --> Requests / Sec counter to find the total number of HTTP requests served by IIS.  For network monitoring, I use Network Interface --> Bytes Received/sec and Network Interface --> Bytes Sent/sec.